# How retrieve data from firebase using query according value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase according to category, the category is dynamic. The user can select a category from a list the are defined. There are one category it's name ALL, my target is, when the user select ALL, then has to retrieve all data, I am able to read the data which has category, but I don't know how to to read the data that doesn't has category.

```
usuarios.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot usuarios : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    DatabaseReference user = usuarios.getRef();
                    String eventUserOwnerKey = user.getKey();



                    //Al elegir la opción all, se quitara todos los filtros y se mostrara todos los eventos


                    if (value!="ALL") {
                        System.out.println("ALALALALALALALALALALALALALALALAL");
                        Query eventos = usuarios.getRef().child("eventos").orderByChild("categoria").equalTo(value);


                        //Aqui compruebo si el adaptado tiene valor o no.
                        //En caso de que tenga, entonces que vacie para que cada que se ejecute la consulta con
                        //Diferente categoria, se vaya vaciando los resultados anteriores

                        if (adapter != null) {
                            adapter.clear();
                        }

                        eventos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot eventos : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    //Recupero el objeto Evento des de la base de datos
                                    Evento evento = eventos.getValue(Evento.class);
                                    resultradoEventos.add(evento);//Guardo en el arraylist los eventos recuperados.
                                    lvEventos = view.findViewById(R.id.lvEventos);

                                    if (getContext() != null) {
                                        adapter = new EventpAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_evento, resultradoEventos);
                                        lvEventos.setAdapter(adapter);

                                        lvEventos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                                Evento evento = (Evento) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DetailEvento.class);
                                                i.putExtra("evento", evento);
                                                i.putExtra("eventUserOwnerKey", eventUserOwnerKey);
                                                startActivity(i);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }else if (value=="ALL"){
                        System.out.println("HOLALALALALALALALALAL");


                    }
                }
```

Here is my Data

```
"usuarios" : {
    "QnUqKgJfq2XxDYcsvp4YnJ2YFhn1" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LgIlXbocvzN3ZpbwuFR" : {
          "caducidad" : "15",
          "categoria" : "DAM",
          "descripcion" : "mac",
          "horaDelEvento" : "mac",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/Uploads%2F538138937?alt=media&token=7d77c944-2037-43a1-ab2b-871ba3068966",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "mac",
          "titol" : "mac"
        },
        "-LgIljoH-AsRchkQ4xbw" : {
          "caducidad" : "67989",
          "categoria" : "DAM",
          "descripcion" : "nadim",
          "horaDelEvento" : "nadim",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/Uploads%2F538138937?alt=media&token=7d77c944-2037-43a1-ab2b-871ba3068966",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "nadim",
          "titol" : "nadim"
        }
      }
    },
    "UvTCjIYMA0btE14QHz7twbdN7zT2" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LdPfYoRre18oGpd3Oda" : {
          "caducidad" : "2019-04-26",
          "categoria" : "SMIX",
          "descripcion" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the",
          "horaDelEvento" : "12:12",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/usuarios%2FUvTCjIYMA0btE14QHz7twbdN7zT2%2Fimagenes%2Fpexels-photo-160107.jpeg?alt=media&token=f0b7b573-8ca4-4fd2-a5e4-da43b967ff4b",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "Aula 33",
          "titol" : "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      }
    },
    "hzqvjnkTdJcyTOPUcEMrAmvEXUo1" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LfofwABcBVf_ID29Iye" : {
          "caducidad" : "12",
          "categoria" : "SMIX",
          "descripcion" : "Fifa",
          "horaDelEvento" : "2",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/Uploads%2F35034?alt=media&token=382a36d6-f12a-4d9b-b67e-0e61e21a77fc",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "Fif",
          "titol" : "Fifaaa"
        }
      }
    },
    "pzgsylJZenYmOAUytReg1TSDNv82" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LgWUjpk8m4YHUHc4mQj" : {
          "caducidad" : "2019-06-04",
          "categoria" : "DAM",
          "descripcion" : "Trial",
          "horaDelEvento" : "15:00",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/usuarios%2FpzgsylJZenYmOAUytReg1TSDNv82%2Fimagenes%2Fmacbook-apple-imac-computer-39284.jpeg?alt=media&token=cb0c0c1d-dd8a-422c-82da-f8bc9ba30e0c",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "Aula:73",
          "titol" : "Trial Today"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my categories

```
"categorias" : {
    "-Lg3sBVLlFv5dnIkqh2t" : {
      "titiolCategoria" : "SMIX"
    },
    "-Lg3t1hokeFkrj2SpgDH" : {
      "titiolCategoria" : "DAM"
    },
    "-LgIaTyAnU_GbHMQLn1I" : {
      "titiolCategoria" : "ALL"
    },
    "-LgWcNmZqpG6tHNCmXgA" : {
      "titiolCategoria" : "AFI"
    }
  },
```

I want show data according to categoria, if user select category ALL, then it's has to show all data are available. Else, it's has to show the data that the category selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two cases:

1. If the value is `ALL` you want to read all users.
2. If the value is not `ALL`, you only want to read users who have that category.

I'd implement that like this:

```
Query eventos = usuarios.getRef().child("eventos");

if (!value.equals("ALL")) {
    eventos = eventos.orderByChild("categoria").equalTo(value);
}

eventos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot eventos : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            ...

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```